# echo $path returns blank on Mac

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

`echo $path` is returning blank for me. The following are contents of my `.bash_profile`.

```
CHANGE PROMPT
export PS1="►►"
export TERM=xterm-color
export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto' GREP_COLOR='1;32'
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad

#PATH
#export PATH="/usr/local/sbin"
#export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin"
#export PATH="$PATH:/Users/suraj/Scripts"
#export PATH="$PATH:/Users/suraj/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs"
```

Notice that I have commented out the path lines but `echo $path` still returns blank if I uncomment them.

Answer (score 4):

Path needs to be in all caps ie $PATH. Bash is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

On your system the variables `$path` and `$PATH` are different and can be defined at the same time.
Unix, and so Linux and BSD, are case sensitive operative systems <sup>[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity)]</sup>  for the commands, the file names in the file systems and the environment variable too.

> Case-sensitivity of variable names also varies between languages and some languages require the use of a certain case in naming certain entities; **Most modern languages are case-sensitive**; some older languages are not. Some languages **reserve certain forms of variable names for their own internal use**...

<sup>From the wiki page about *Case Sensitivity* <sup>[[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28computer_science%29#Naming_conventions)]</sup></sup>

Usually the environment variable under the Bourne Shell (and all the ones that present backward compatibility with `sh`) are written in capital letters (e.g. `PATH`,`DISPLAY`, `PS1`, `HOME`,`HOSTNAME`,`BASH`,`BASHOPTS`... write `set | less` to have an idea if you are in bash).